source ~/.bashrc returns "Command not found
Command 'shopt' not found, did you mean:
  command 'shout' from deb libshout-tools
Try: sudo apt install <deb name>
Command 'shopt' not found, did you mean:
  command 'shout' from deb libshout-tools
Try: sudo apt install <deb name>
Command 'shopt' not found, did you mean:
  command 'shout' from deb libshout-tools
Try: sudo apt install <deb name>
Command 'shopt' not found, did you mean:
  command 'shout' from deb libshout-tools
Try: sudo apt install <deb name>
complete: command not found
complete: command not found
complete: command not found
complete: command not found
complete: command not found
complete: command not found
complete: command not found
complete: command not found
complete: command not found
_comp_dequote__initialize:unset:2: no such hash table element: 
/usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion:615: parse error near `&'
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]\[\033[;32m\]┌──(\[\033[1;34m\]\u㉿\h\[\033[;32m\])-[\[\033[0;1m\]\w\[\033[;32m\]]\n\[\033[;32m\]└─\[\033[1;34m\]$\[\033[0m\] 


It looks like you are trying to source ~/.bashrc into a shell that is not bash - possibly zsh?

And your shell (try echo "$SHELL") is not interpreting your prompt sequence in $PS1. Do /bin/bash to open a bash shell (that understands shopt). Find your login shell with getent passwd $USER. Change your login shell by reading man chsh, and cat /etc/shells.

... $SHELL will likely contain the same information as the password database - if you want to know your current shell, try echo $0
